# kivy how to use online images in python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to make a button which uses an image from URL.

```
icon= str('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-256.png')

self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=(icon), size=(100,100), size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), on_press=callback, pos_hint={"x":0.90, "top":1.0}))

class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass
```

It shows as an white image for some reason. Could anyone help me please?

Comment: AsyncImage: https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.image.html

Comment: ValueError: ImageButton.source accept only str

Comment: I made it as a str and it says that it cant be recognised.

Comment: If you have used the same syntax that is wrong in your example, you should not use `source = (icon)`, it should only be `source = icon`

Comment: `icon = AsyncImage(source='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-256.png')`
-
`self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=(str(icon)), size=(100,100), size_hint=(0.1, 0.1), on_press=callback, pos_hint={"x":0.90, "top":1.0}))`

Comment: It still says 'Error reading file'

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. It is important that you (at least) share your `ImageButton` class.

Comment: class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, Image):
    pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As eyllanesc comments, you must use `AsyncImage` subclass to load the image asynchronously from the server. Otherwise, the image will not be available when you instantiate the widget.

On the other hand, the code you show in your comment;

```
icon = AsyncImage(source='https://.../icon.png')
self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=(str(icon)))
```

is also incorrect, You are trying to pass to `source` (StringPropery) an instance of `AsyncImage`. The simple solution to that is to inherit from `AsyncImage` and not from `Image`:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.image import AsyncImage
from kivy.uix.behaviors import ButtonBehavior

from kivy.core.window import Window
Window.clearcolor = (1, 1, 1, 1)


class ImageButton(ButtonBehavior, AsyncImage):
    pass


class MainWindow(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        icon = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/flat-ui-icons-24-px/24/eye-24-256.png'
        self.add_widget(ImageButton(source=icon))


class Test(App):
    def build(self):
        return MainWindow()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    Test().run()
```

[image]